# How to get distribution across combination of variables in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have following DF:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("IR-1", "IR-2", "IR-3", "IR-4", "IR-4", 
"IR-4", "IR-5", "IR-5", "IR-5", "IR-6", "IR-7", "IR-8", "IR-9", 
"IR-10"), Var1 = c("A1", "", "A2", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A1", "A2", 
"A3", "", "A2", "", "A2", ""), Var2 = c("X1,X2,X3", "", "X1,X4", 
"X1,X2,X3", "X1,X2,X3", "X1,X2,X3", "X1,X3", "X1,X3", "X1,X3", 
"", "X1,X2,X3", "X1,X2,X3", "X8", ""), Type = c("New", "Old", 
"New", "New", "New", "New", "New", "New", "New", "New", "New", 
"New", "New", "Old")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))

> df
ID       Var1         Var2              Type
IR-1     A1           X1,X2,X3          New
IR-2                                    Old
IR-3     A2           X1,X4             New
IR-4     A1           X1,X2,X3          New
IR-4     A3           X1,X2,X3          New
IR-4     A2           X1,X2,X3          New
IR-5     A1           X1,X3             New
IR-5     A2           X1,X3             New
IR-5     A3           X1,X3             New
IR-6                                    New
IR-7     A2           X1,X2,X3          New
IR-8                  X1,X2,X3          New
IR-9     A2           X8                New
IR-10                                   Old
```

By utilizing the `df`, I want to understand the distribution of `Var1` across `Var1` and `Var2` combine for a unique `ID`.

Where,

- Total = Count of Unique `ID` and in horizontal row count of variable hit (i.e var1 & var2) inclusive for those `ID`
- Excl_count = If a particular `ID` has only 1 value as part of either `Var1` or `Var2`
- Blank_Var1 = Count of unique `ID` where `Var1` is Null/NA/Blank or 0
- Blank_Var2 = Count of unique `ID` where `Var2` is Null/NA/Blank or 0
- Blank_Both = Count of unique `ID` where both `Var1` and `Var2` are either Null/NA/Blank or 0
- Blank_New = Count of unique `ID` where both `Var1` and `Var2` are either Null/NA/Blank or 0 having `Type` = New
- Blank_Old = Count of unique `ID` where both `Var1` and `Var2` are either Null/NA/Blank or 0 having `Type` = Old
- Non_Blank = Count of unique `ID` where either `Var1` or `Var2` are not Null/NA/Blank or 0
- Rest is check the across mapping. For example vertical varialbes (i.e A1 to A3, and X1 to KL) checks how many of them hit exclusively without hitting any other value. Also, it checks `A1` hit with which other variable in the entire variable list

Required Data<-

```
Variables   Excl_Count   %         A1   A2   A3   X1   X2   X3   X4   GT   XN   XP   X8   KP   KL  
Total       10           100.00%   2    4    2    6    4    5    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
Blank_Var1  4             40.00%   0    0    0    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
Blank_Var2  3             30.00%   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
Blank_Both  3             30.00%   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
Blank_New   1             33.33%   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
Blank_Old   2             66.66%   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
Non_Blank   7             70.00%   3    5    2    6    4    5    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
A1          1             16.67%   0    2    2    3    2    3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
A2          3             50.00%   2    0    2    4    2    3    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
A3          0              0.00%   2    2    0    2    1    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
X1          0              0.00%   3    5    2    0    4    5    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
X2          0              0.00%   2    2    2    5    0    4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
X3          0              0.00%   3    3    2    5    4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
X4          0              0.00%   0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
GT          0              0.00%   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
XN          0              0.00%   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
XP          0              0.00%   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
X8          1             16.67%   0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
KP          0              0.00%   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
KL          0              0.00%   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: This is 9 questions, please ask one question at a time. Also, please post data in `dput` format, edit the question with the output of `dput(DF)`.

Comment: Very often, the dificulty you face in problems like this (which is actually a set multiple problems) is that your dataset is not [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html).  Clearly, your dataset is not tidy here.  Once you make you data tidy, I suspect deriving the statistics you want will be trivial.

Comment: @RuiBarradas- Apologies, I'll break the questions into different parts. I tried but couldn't achieve the required output.

Comment: Similar problem here! `non_blank` values are greater than `Total`?

Comment: what do `excl_count` for `X1` mean which is `0`? similarly, the `%` isn.t adding up to 100

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do the values on 8th to last row, 2nd and 3rd columns mean in your sample output. However, for rest of your code, you may proceed as follows.  The code is based on your another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66151696/how-to-classify-variable-count-on-multiple-condition-in-r/66154992#66154992)

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("IR-1", "IR-2", "IR-3", "IR-4", "IR-4", 
                            "IR-4", "IR-5", "IR-5", "IR-5", "IR-6", "IR-7", "IR-8", "IR-9", 
                            "IR-10"), Var1 = c("A1", "", "A2", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A1", "A2", 
                                               "A3", "", "A2", "", "A2", ""), Var2 = c("X1,X2,X3", "", "X1,X4", 
                                                                                       "X1,X2,X3", "X1,X2,X3", "X1,X2,X3", "X1,X3", "X1,X3", "X1,X3", 
                                                                                       "", "X1,X2,X3", "X1,X2,X3", "X8", ""), Type = c("New", "Old", 
                                                                                                                                       "New", "New", "New", "New", "New", "New", "New", "New", "New", 
                                                                                                                                       "New", "New", "Old")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  -14L))
library(tidyverse)
#first dataobject
df1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(Var1) %>%
  mutate(Total = n_distinct(ID),
         Blank_var1 = n_distinct(ID[is.na(Var1) | Var1 == "" | Var1 == "0"]),
         Blank_var2 = n_distinct(ID[is.na(Var2) | Var2 == "" | Var2 == "0"]),
         Blank_Both = n_distinct(ID[(is.na(Var1) | Var1 == "" | Var1 == "0") & (is.na(Var2) | Var2 == "" | Var2 == "0")]),
         Blank_new = n_distinct(ID[(is.na(Var1) | Var1 == "" | Var1 == "0") & (is.na(Var2) | Var2 == "" | Var2 == "0") & (Type == "New")]),
         Blank_old = n_distinct(ID[(is.na(Var1) | Var1 == "" | Var1 == "0") & (is.na(Var2) | Var2 == "" | Var2 == "0") & (Type == "Old")]),
         non_blank = Total - Blank_Both) %>%
  select(-c(ID, Var2, Type)) %>%
  filter(!(is.na(Var1) | Var1 == "" | Var1 == "0")) %>%
  pivot_longer(-Var1) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = name, names_from = Var1, values_from = "value", values_fn = min) %>%
  ungroup()

#second object
df2 <- df %>% separate(Var2, into = paste0("Var2", 1:3), sep = ",") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(Var21, Var22, Var23), names_to = "name", values_to = "Var2") %>%
  select(-name) %>%
  filter(!(is.na(Var2) | Var2 == "")) %>%
  group_by(Var2) %>%
  mutate(Total = n_distinct(ID),
         Blank_var1 = n_distinct(ID[is.na(Var1) | Var1 == "" | Var1 == "0"]),
         Blank_var2 = n_distinct(ID[is.na(Var2) | Var2 == "" | Var2 == "0"]),
         Blank_Both = n_distinct(ID[(is.na(Var1) | Var1 == "" | Var1 == "0") & (is.na(Var2) | Var2 == "" | Var2 == "0")]),
         Blank_new = n_distinct(ID[(is.na(Var1) | Var1 == "" | Var1 == "0") & (is.na(Var2) | Var2 == "" | Var2 == "0") & (Type == "New")]),
         Blank_old = n_distinct(ID[(is.na(Var1) | Var1 == "" | Var1 == "0") & (is.na(Var2) | Var2 == "" | Var2 == "0") & (Type == "Old")]),
         non_blank = Total - Blank_Both) %>%
  select(-c(ID, Var1, Type)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-Var2) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = name, names_from = Var2, values_from = "value", values_fn = min)

#third object
df3 <- df %>%
  summarise(Total = n_distinct(ID),
            Blank_var1 = n_distinct(ID[is.na(Var1) | Var1 == "" | Var1 == "0"]),
            Blank_var2 = n_distinct(ID[is.na(Var2) | Var2 == "" | Var2 == "0"]),
            Blank_Both = n_distinct(ID[(is.na(Var1) | Var1 == "" | Var1 == "0") & (is.na(Var2) | Var2 == "" | Var2 == "0")]),
            Blank_new = n_distinct(ID[(is.na(Var1) | Var1 == "" | Var1 == "0") & (is.na(Var2) | Var2 == "" | Var2 == "0") & (Type == "New")]),
            Blank_old = n_distinct(ID[(is.na(Var1) | Var1 == "" | Var1 == "0") & (is.na(Var2) | Var2 == "" | Var2 == "0") & (Type == "Old")]),
            non_blank = Total - Blank_Both) %>% pivot_longer(cols = 1:7, names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Excl_count") %>%
  mutate(`%` = case_when(Variable == "Total" ~ "100.00%",
                         Variable %in% c("Blank_var1", "Blank_var2", "Blank_Both", "non_blank") ~ paste0(round(Excl_count*100/Excl_count[Variable == "Total"], 2), "%"),
                         Variable == "Blank_new" | Variable == "Blank_old" ~ paste0(round(Excl_count*100/Excl_count[Variable == "Blank_Both"], 2), "%")))


#max values in Var2
n1 <- 1 + max(str_count(df$Var2, ","))
#Tidy data
df_tidy <- df %>% separate(Var2, into = paste0("Var2", 1:n1)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(ID, Type), names_to = "Variable") %>%
  mutate(Variable = if_else(str_detect(Variable, "Var2"), "Var2", Variable)) %>%
  filter(!(is.na(value) | value == ""))

#fourth data object
df4 <- merge(df_tidy, df_tidy, by = c("ID", "Type"), all = T) %>%
  filter(! value.x == value.y) %>%
  select(ID, Variable = value.x, value.y) %>%
  group_by(Variable, value.y) %>%
  mutate(val = n_distinct(ID)) %>%
  select(-ID) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Variable, names_from = value.y, values_from = val, values_fn = min, values_fill = 0) %>%
  mutate(Excl_count = NA,
         `%` = NA)
  


#final
rbind(merge(df3, merge(df1, df2, by.x = "name", by.y = "name", sort = F), 
      by.x = "Variable", by.y = "name", sort = F), df4)

     Variable Excl_count       % A1 A2 A3 X1 X2 X3 X4 X8
1       Total         10 100.00%  3  5  2  6  4  5  1  1
2  Blank_var1          4     40%  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0
3  Blank_var2          3     30%  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
4  Blank_Both          3     30%  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
5   Blank_new          1  33.33%  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
6   Blank_old          2  66.67%  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
7   non_blank          7     70%  3  5  2  6  4  5  1  1
8          A1         NA    <NA>  0  2  2  3  2  3  0  0
9          X1         NA    <NA>  3  4  2  0  4  5  1  0
10         X2         NA    <NA>  2  2  1  4  0  4  0  0
11         X3         NA    <NA>  3  3  2  5  4  0  0  0
12         A2         NA    <NA>  2  0  2  4  2  3  1  1
13         X4         NA    <NA>  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0
14         A3         NA    <NA>  2  2  0  2  1  2  0  0
15         X8         NA    <NA>  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
```