# How to classify variable count on multiple condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have following DF:

DF<-

```
ID       Var1         Var2              Type
IR-1     A1           X1,X2,X3          New
IR-2                                    Old
IR-3     A2           X1,X4             New
IR-4     A1           X1,X2,X3          New
IR-4     A3           X1,X2,X3          New
IR-4     A2           X1,X2,X3          New
IR-5     A1           X1,X3             New
IR-5     A2           X1,X3             New
IR-5     A3           X1,X3             New
IR-6                                    New
IR-7     A2           X1,X2,X3          New
IR-8                  X1,X2,X3          New
IR-9     A2           X8                New
IR-10                                   Old
```

Required Output

```
Variables   Excl_Count   %         A1   A2   A3   X1   X2   X3   X4   GT   XN   XP   X8   KP   KL  
Total       10           100.00%   3    5    2    6    4    5    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
Blank_Var1  4             40.00%   0    0    0    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
Blank_Var2  3             30.00%   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
Blank_Both  3             30.00%   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
Blank_New   1             33.33%   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
Blank_Old   2             66.66%   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
Non_Blank   7             70.00%   3    5    2    6    4    5    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
```

By utilizing the `df`, I want to understand the distribution of `Var1` across `Var1` and `Var2` combine for a unique `ID`.

Where,

- Total = Count of Unique `ID` and in horizontal row count of variable hit (i.e var1 & var2) inclusive for those `ID`
- Excl_count = If a particular `ID` has only 1 value as part of either `Var1` or `Var2`
- Blank_Var1 = Count of unique `ID` where `Var1` is Null/NA/Blank or 0
- Blank_Var2 = Count of unique `ID` where `Var2` is Null/NA/Blank or 0
- Blank_Both = Count of unique `ID` where both `Var1` and `Var2` are either Null/NA/Blank or 0
- Blank_New = Count of unique `ID` where both `Var1` and `Var2` are either Null/NA/Blank or 0 having `Type` = New
- Blank_Old = Count of unique `ID` where both `Var1` and `Var2` are either Null/NA/Blank or 0 having `Type` = Old
- Non_Blank = Count of unique `ID` where either `Var1` or `Var2` are not Null/NA/Blank or 0
- A1 to KL are count corresponding to each row.

Below is the code that I have tried but not working as expected -

```
library(RMySQL)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
    
# Count Total
    Total <- DF %>%
      dplyr::group_by(ID) %>%
      dplyr::mutate(count = n())
    # Excl_Count 
    Excl_Count  <- DF %>% 
      dplyr::group_by(ID) %>%
      dplyr::summarize("Count" = n_distinct(ID))
    # Blank_Var1
    Blank_Var1 <- DF %>% dplyr::filter(Var1 ==  '') %>%
      dplyr::group_by(ID) %>%
      dplyr::summarize("Count" = sum(count))
    # Blank_Var2
    Blank_Var2 <- DF %>% dplyr::filter(Var2 ==  '') %>%
      dplyr::group_by(ID) %>%
      dplyr::summarize("Count" = sum(count))
    # Blank_Both
    Blank_Both <- DF %>% dplyr::filter(Var1 ==  '' & Var2 == '') %>%
      dplyr::group_by(ID) %>%
      dplyr::summarize("Count" = sum(count))
    # Blank_New
    Blank_New <- DF %>% dplyr::filter(Var1 ==  '' & Type == 'New') %>%
      dplyr::group_by(ID) %>%
      dplyr::summarize("Count" = sum(count))
    # Blank_Old
    Blank_Old <- DF %>% dplyr::filter(Var1 ==  '' & Type == 'Old') %>%
      dplyr::group_by(ID) %>%
      dplyr::summarize("Count" = sum(count))
```

Dput<-

```
structure(list(ID = c("IR-1", "IR-2", "IR-3", "IR-4", "IR-4", 
"IR-4", "IR-5", "IR-5", "IR-5", "IR-6", "IR-7", "IR-8", "IR-9", 
"IR-10"), Var1 = c("A1", "", "A2", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A1", "A2", 
"A3", "", "A2", "", "A2", ""), Var2 = c("X1,X2,X3", "", "X1,X4", 
"X1,X2,X3", "X1,X2,X3", "X1,X2,X3", "X1,X3", "X1,X3", "X1,X3", 
"", "X1,X2,X3", "X1,X2,X3", "X8", ""), Type = c("New", "Old", 
"New", "New", "New", "New", "New", "New", "New", "New", "New", 
"New", "New", "Old")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

Comment: Can you explain what you attempted so far and where you got stuck

Comment: I am pretty sure that, you can achieve at least one of the conditions you desire on your own. So please show your effort firstly before asking a help.

Comment: @maydin-Updated the code that I have tried, but not working.

Comment: I cannot understand! why `A1` for `Total` is 2? why `X1` 6?  Too confusing?  Your code is wrong from first step itself? what is `DISTINCT`?

Comment: what are `GT`, `XP` `KP` etc.?

Comment: @AnilGoyal- It was `n_distinct`. My bad, typo error.

Comment: @AnilGoyal- `A1` to `KL` are a distinct count of particular flag corresponding to each row. For example, Suppose 4 ID has blank Var1 then we need to check what is the Var2 count for those Ids.

Comment: I still cannot understand columns in req output other than first 3 columns?  Please explain some with explanation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228572/discussion-between-user9211845-and-anilgoyal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create three intermediate objects (`df1`, `df2` and `df3`) and proceed as follows

```
#load libraries
library(tidyverse)
```

## revised dput

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("IR-1", "IR-2", "IR-3", "IR-4", "IR-4", 
                            "IR-4", "IR-5", "IR-5", "IR-5", "IR-6", "IR-7", "IR-8", "IR-9", 
                            "IR-10"), Var1 = c("A1", "", "A2", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A1", "A2", 
                                               "A3", "", "A2", "", "A2", ""), Var2 = c("", "", "X1,X4", 
                                                                                       "X1,X2,X3", "X1,X2,X3", "X1,X2,X3", "X1,X3", "X1,X3", "X1,X3", 
                                                                                       "", "X1,X2,X3", "X1,X2,X3", "X8", ""), Type = c("New", "Old", 
                                                                                                                                       "New", "New", "New", "New", "New", "New", "New", "New", "New", 
                                                                                                                                       "New", "New", "Old")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  -14L))

> df
      ID Var1     Var2 Type
1   IR-1   A1           New
2   IR-2                Old
3   IR-3   A2    X1,X4  New
4   IR-4   A1 X1,X2,X3  New
5   IR-4   A2 X1,X2,X3  New
6   IR-4   A3 X1,X2,X3  New
7   IR-5   A1    X1,X3  New
8   IR-5   A2    X1,X3  New
9   IR-5   A3    X1,X3  New
10  IR-6                New
11  IR-7   A2 X1,X2,X3  New
12  IR-8      X1,X2,X3  New
13  IR-9   A2       X8  New
14 IR-10                Old
```

In the above revised data, I emptied one row for `var2` for `ID-1`

## Code

(Assuming that maximum of three flags in `Var2`) *otherwise modify `separate` argument accordingly*

```
df1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(Var1) %>%
  mutate(Total = n_distinct(ID),
         Blank_var1 = n_distinct(ID[is.na(Var1) | Var1 == "" | Var1 == "0"]),
         Blank_var2 = n_distinct(ID[is.na(Var2) | Var2 == "" | Var2 == "0"]),
         Blank_Both = n_distinct(ID[(is.na(Var1) | Var1 == "" | Var1 == "0") & (is.na(Var2) | Var2 == "" | Var2 == "0")]),
         Blank_new = n_distinct(ID[(is.na(Var1) | Var1 == "" | Var1 == "0") & (is.na(Var2) | Var2 == "" | Var2 == "0") & (Type == "New")]),
         Blank_old = n_distinct(ID[(is.na(Var1) | Var1 == "" | Var1 == "0") & (is.na(Var2) | Var2 == "" | Var2 == "0") & (Type == "Old")]),
         non_blank = Total - Blank_Both) %>%
  select(-c(ID, Var2, Type)) %>%
  filter(!(is.na(Var1) | Var1 == "" | Var1 == "0")) %>%
  pivot_longer(-Var1) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = name, names_from = Var1, values_from = "value", values_fn = min) %>%
  ungroup()

# Check that Blank_var2 values aren't empty
# A tibble: 7 x 4
  name          A1    A2    A3
  <chr>      <int> <int> <int>
1 Total          3     5     2
2 Blank_var1     0     0     0
3 Blank_var2     1     0     0
4 Blank_Both     0     0     0
5 Blank_new      0     0     0
6 Blank_old      0     0     0
7 non_blank      3     5     2

#Second
  
df2 <- df %>% separate(Var2, into = paste0("Var2", 1:3), sep = ",") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(Var21, Var22, Var23), names_to = "name", values_to = "Var2") %>%
  select(-name) %>%
  filter(!(is.na(Var2) | Var2 == "")) %>%
  group_by(Var2) %>%
  mutate(Total = n_distinct(ID),
         Blank_var1 = n_distinct(ID[is.na(Var1) | Var1 == "" | Var1 == "0"]),
         Blank_var2 = n_distinct(ID[is.na(Var2) | Var2 == "" | Var2 == "0"]),
         Blank_Both = n_distinct(ID[(is.na(Var1) | Var1 == "" | Var1 == "0") & (is.na(Var2) | Var2 == "" | Var2 == "0")]),
         Blank_new = n_distinct(ID[(is.na(Var1) | Var1 == "" | Var1 == "0") & (is.na(Var2) | Var2 == "" | Var2 == "0") & (Type == "New")]),
         Blank_old = n_distinct(ID[(is.na(Var1) | Var1 == "" | Var1 == "0") & (is.na(Var2) | Var2 == "" | Var2 == "0") & (Type == "Old")]),
         non_blank = Total - Blank_Both) %>%
  select(-c(ID, Var1, Type)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-Var2) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = name, names_from = Var2, values_from = "value", values_fn = min)

# Check that blank_var1 isn't empty this time
# A tibble: 7 x 6
  name          X1    X4    X2    X3    X8
  <chr>      <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 Total          5     1     3     4     1
2 Blank_var1     1     0     1     1     0
3 Blank_var2     0     0     0     0     0
4 Blank_Both     0     0     0     0     0
5 Blank_new      0     0     0     0     0
6 Blank_old      0     0     0     0     0
7 non_blank      5     1     3     4     1

df3 <- df %>%
  summarise(Total = n_distinct(ID),
         Blank_var1 = n_distinct(ID[is.na(Var1) | Var1 == "" | Var1 == "0"]),
         Blank_var2 = n_distinct(ID[is.na(Var2) | Var2 == "" | Var2 == "0"]),
         Blank_Both = n_distinct(ID[(is.na(Var1) | Var1 == "" | Var1 == "0") & (is.na(Var2) | Var2 == "" | Var2 == "0")]),
         Blank_new = n_distinct(ID[(is.na(Var1) | Var1 == "" | Var1 == "0") & (is.na(Var2) | Var2 == "" | Var2 == "0") & (Type == "New")]),
         Blank_old = n_distinct(ID[(is.na(Var1) | Var1 == "" | Var1 == "0") & (is.na(Var2) | Var2 == "" | Var2 == "0") & (Type == "Old")]),
         non_blank = Total - Blank_Both) %>% pivot_longer(cols = 1:7, names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Excl_count") %>%
  mutate(`%` = case_when(Variable == "Total" ~ "100.00%",
                         Variable %in% c("Blank_var1", "Blank_var2", "Blank_Both", "non_blank") ~ paste0(round(Excl_count*100/Excl_count[Variable == "Total"], 2), "%"),
                         Variable == "Blank_new" | Variable == "Blank_old" ~ paste0(round(Excl_count*100/Excl_count[Variable == "Blank_Both"], 2), "%")))

> df3
# A tibble: 7 x 3
  Variable   Excl_count `%`    
  <chr>           <int> <chr>  
1 Total              10 100.00%
2 Blank_var1          4 40%    
3 Blank_var2          4 40%    
4 Blank_Both          3 30%    
5 Blank_new           1 33.33% 
6 Blank_old           2 66.67% 
7 non_blank           7 70%
```

Lastly, `merge` all three to obtain this..

```
merge(df3, merge(df1, df2, by.x = "name", by.y = "name", sort = F), 
      by.x = "Variable", by.y = "name", sort = F)

    Variable Excl_count       % A1 A2 A3 X1 X4 X2 X3 X8
1      Total         10 100.00%  3  5  2  5  1  3  4  1
2 Blank_var1          4     40%  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  0
3 Blank_var2          4     40%  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
4 Blank_Both          3     30%  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
5  Blank_new          1  33.33%  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
6  Blank_old          2  66.67%  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
7  non_blank          7     70%  3  5  2  5  1  3  4  1
```

## explanation

- You have to mutate three times on similar lines
- Firstly by `group_by` on `Var1`
- Secondly by `group_by` on `Var2` but after separating and pivoting longer these into one single column
- Lastly/thirdly without any grouping (and hence I used `summarise`)
- basically the argument within mutate/summarise in all three intermediate objects is exactly same and copied/paste
- Lastly I used `merge`  from `baseR` (you can optionally use left_join)

Comment: Something is wrong in `Blank_var2` as all the variables can't be 0. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I edited `dput` a bit to show you that code is correct.  In fact for `Var2` flags `blank_var2` will always be `0` and similarly for `Var1` flags `blank_var1` values will always be `0`